# How to only print out highest/smallest array values in c++

Tags: c++, structure

Good day, I'm having difficulty on the last two parts of my program where it's supposed to only output players who got maximum/minimum scores, I need help on how to do it because I'm really confused. If it's also alright to provide some explanations I'd really appreciate it.

**I tried this approach:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double lrgst, lrgst2, lrgst3;
  int numbers[5];

  lrgst = lrgst2 = lrgst3;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> numbers[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > lrgst) {
      lrgst3 = lrgst2;
      lrgst2 = lrgst;
      lrgst = numbers[i];
    } else if (numbers[i] > lrgst2) {
      lrgst3 = lrgst2;
      lrgst2 = numbers[i];
    } else if (numbers[i] > lrgst3) {
      lrgst3 = numbers[i];
    }
  }

  cout << "largest are: " << lrgst << " " << lrgst2 << " " << lrgst3;
}
```

**this is my actual code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct playerdata {
  char name[50];

  int age, score1, score2;
  double average;
};

int main() {

  int choice, i = 1, j = 1, z = 1, backtomain2;
  char backtomain;

  playerdata p1[10];

  do {
    for (int a = 0; a < 47; a++) {
      cout << "=";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for (int b = 0; b < 22; b++) {
      cout << " ";

      if (b == 21) {
        cout << "MENU \n";
      }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < 47; c++) {
      ocut << "=";
    }

    cout << " "
            "\n1. Add record\n"
            "2. View players records\n"
            "3. Compute for the average\n"
            "4. Show the player(s) who gets the max average.\n"
            "5. Show the player(s) who gets the min average.\n"
            "6. Exit\n"
            "Enter your choice:";

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {
      cout << "Add player data" << endl;

      do {
        cout << "Enter player " << i << " nickname:";
        cin >> p1[i].name;

        cout << "Enter player " << i << " age:";
        cin >> p1[i].age;

        cout << "Enter player " << i << " score 1:";
        cin >> p1[i].score1;

        cout << "Enter player " << i << " score 2:";
        cin >> p1[i].score2;

        cout << "Enter again? (Y/N)";
        cin >> backtomain;

        i++;
      }

      while (backtomain != 'N' && backtomain != 'n' && i < 7);

      if (choice == 2) {
        cout << "Player records" << endl;

        cout << "Player nickname  "
             << "Player age  "
             << "  player score 1"
             << "  
            player score 2\n ";

            for (z = 1; z <= i - 1; z++) {

          cout << p1[z].name << " " << p1[z].age << "" << p1[z].score1 << ""
               << p1[z].score2 << "\n";
        }

        cout << "Press 1 to go back to main menu\n";

        cin >> backtomain;
      }

      if (choice == 3) {
        cout << "Computing for average...\n";

        for (int d = 1; d <= i - 1; d++) {
          p1[d].average = (p1[d].score1 + p1[d].score2) / 2.0;

          cout << "\n" << p1[d].average << "\n";
        }

        cout << "Press 1 to go back to main menu\n";
        cin >> backtomain;
      }

      if (choice == 4) {
        cout << "Player(s) who got the max average:\n";

        cout << "\nPress 1 to go back to main menu";
        cin >> backtomain;
      }

      if (choice == 5) {
        cout << "player(s) who got the min average: \n";

        cout << "Press 1 to go back to main menu";
        cin >> backtomain;
      }
    }

    while (choice != 6);
  }
```

Comment: whats the difference between "this approach" and "your actual code" ? Please show the code that the question is about. Include input, output and expected output. And please review formatting, too many blank lines make it difficult to read the code

Comment: Bin it. Replace with something like `auto thingy = std::minmax_element(std::begin(whatever), std::end(whatever));` and read the results out of `thingy`.

Comment: @Bathsheba it is `std::minmax_element`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Indeed, perhaps I need another coffee.

Comment: @Batsheba made the same mistake recently. Its a little unpleasant that those are two different functions, I guess the only reason is to allow comparing iterators via `minmax`

Comment: I think the question is a fair question and the proposed answer is a good solution. Another comment: in your example you don not initialize "lrgst = lrgst2 = lrgst3;". You won't need this line in the proposed solution, but it should be "lrgst = lrgst2 = lrgst3 = 0;" or some other value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the array of players for that

```
int n = sizeof(p1)/ sizeof(p1[0]);
sort(p1, p1+n, compPlayer);
//larget at pl[0]
//smallest at pl[9]
```

where

```
bool compPlayer(playerdata p1, playerdata p2) {
    return (p1.score1+p1.score2) > (p2.score1+p2.score2);
    //use score incase average has not been calculated for all players yet
}
```